# Discord.py Button Not Letting Multiple Users Use The Button At Once

Tags: python, button

```
@client.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(
        "Support Tickets",
        components = [
            Button(label = "General", style=ButtonStyle.red)
        ]
    )
    while True:
      interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", timeout=None, check = lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("General"))

      await interaction.respond(content = "Creating The Ticket...")
    
      with open("data.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

      ticket_number = int(data["ticket-counter"])
      ticket_number += 1

      category_channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(804496358387351562)
      ticketlog_channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(819784960823132201)
      ticket_channel = await category_channel.create_text_channel(
      "ticket-{}".format(ticket_number))
      await ticket_channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.get_role(ctx.guild.id),
                          send_messages=False,
                          read_messages=False)
    
      for role_id in data["valid-roles"]:
        role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)

        await ticket_channel.set_permissions(role,
                                              send_messages=True,
                                              read_messages=True,
                                              add_reactions=True,
                                              embed_links=True,
                                              attach_files=True,
                                              read_message_history=True,
                                              external_emojis=True)

      await ticket_channel.set_permissions(interaction.author,
                                              send_messages=True,
                                              read_messages=True,
                                              add_reactions=True,
                                              embed_links=True,
                                              attach_files=True,
                                              read_message_history=True,
                                              external_emojis=True)

      staff_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Support Team")

      data["ticket-channel-ids"].append(ticket_channel.id)

      data["ticket-counter"] = int(ticket_number)
      with open("data.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

      em = discord.Embed(title="Ticket Logs",
                            description=f"",
                            color=0x00a8ff)
      em.add_field(name="Creator", value=f"{interaction.author.mention}", inline=True)
      em.add_field(name="Ticket", value=f"{ticket_channel.name}", inline=True)
      time = datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('America/Denver'))
      formatted = time.strftime("%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p")
      em.set_footer(text=formatted)

      await ticketlog_channel.send(embed=em)

      await ticket_channel.send(
        f'{interaction.author.mention}, please answer the following questions.'
      )
      await ticket_channel.send('-----------------------------------------------')

      def check(message):
        return message.channel == ticket_channel and message.author == interaction.author

      a = discord.Embed(title="Question 1",
                       description=f"Is your issue with our forums, discord, or an in-game server? (Please specify which server)",
                       color=0x00a8ff)

      await ticket_channel.send(embed=a)

      question1 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

      b = discord.Embed(title="Question 2",
                       description=f"What is your IGN? (Forums username)",
                       color=0x00a8ff)

      await ticket_channel.send(embed=b)

      question2 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

      c = discord.Embed(title="Question 3",
                       description=f"Please explain your issue.",
                       color=0x00a8ff)

      await ticket_channel.send(embed=c)

      question3 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

      d = discord.Embed(title="Question 4",
                       description=f"Please provide any evidence, if applicable.",
                       color=0x00a8ff)

      await ticket_channel.send(embed=d)

      question4 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

      await ticket_channel.send(f'{question1.content} {question2.content} {question3.content} {question4.content}')
```

So a little bit of a backstory. I'm currently trying to make a simple ticket system via a button. I would like the button to ask questions once the button is clicked and the channel has been configured correctly. Right now everything works, but only one user at a time (if the user is in the def check(message) process can use the button or it will give them the transaction failed message. I have tried literally anything and everything I can think of to fix this, but haven't had any luck so far. If you could assist me that would be so amazing! Thank you!

Comment: check if the interaction.user.id is ctx.author.id

Comment: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/azuxemoneq.py is my code. It still has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to don't use the while loop and inside that put client.wait_for()
Create an event function named _on_button_click() and here use a check to see if the message is correct and then ask the question